# ElasticSearch check if boolean field is "true" (string) and not true (boolean)

Tags: elasticsearch

We have an index with a field mapped as boolean.
Boolean fields accepts either true / "true" / false / "false" / "" (false)

I need to update documents with "true"/"false"/"" fields to true/false/false.

Is there a way to filter the documents with boolean stored as strings?

I already tried things like:

```
GET index_name/_search
{
  "query" : {
    "bool": {
      "filter" : {
          "script" : {
              "script" : {
                "lang":   "painless",
                "source": "doc['is_visible'].value===params.equality",
                "params": {
                  "equality": "true"
                }
              }
              
          }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

and

```
GET index_name/_search
{
    "query": {
        "bool" : {
            "filter" : {
                "script" : {
                    "script" : {
                        "inline": "if(doc['is_visible'] instanceof String) return true;",
                        "lang": "painless"
                     }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

but without the expected results.

A complete update isn't viable because the index has 600+ millions documents.

ES Version 6.8

Answer (score 0):

As I tested, `true` (bool) and `\"true\"` (string) do not differ in doc values but they differ in source. In the filter context, elasticsearch lets users to access `doc_values` but not the `_source`. `_source` can be accessed in update context. Following query may help you:

```
POST {index_name}/_update_by_query
{
  "script": {
    "source": """
      if(ctx._source.is_visible == 'true') {
         ctx._source.is_visible = true;
      }
    """,
    "lang": "painless"
  }
}
```

It will go over all the documents anyway, but it will update only the required ones.

Comment: Unlucky not sir.
I did as stated but I got all the documents updated, not only the ones with strings
What is the ES version you tested?

Comment: I tested the above example on v7.6.2. But I just tested it on v6.8.1 and it is still working. If you are looking at `updated` in the `update_by_query` result, it will show the number of all documents, because it checks all of them. But because of the conditions in the script, it will only update the fields with string `\"true\"` value. To test it, maybe you can create a dummy index and add new field according to the condition. You should see that documents with `\"true\"` will have the new field, documents with boolean `true` will not have the new field.